# Material UI Datagrid Checkbox selection with Server side pagination clearing selectedModel. I want to persist selectedModel state while changing page

Tags: checkbox, material-ui, pagination, datagrid

I am using Material UI's Data Grid and using server side pagination with custom Pagination Component. When I select checkbox on same page it is working fine but with changing page my selectionModel set to emtpy array. I am calling api on page change and updating row and totalCount State

```
           <CustomizedDataGrid
                    rows={row}
                    loading={loading}
                    columns={didColoumn}
                    autoWidth={true}
                    scrollbarSize={10}
                    rowCount={totalCount}
                    autoHeight={true}
                    getRowId={(row) => row.didId}
                    disableColumnMenu
                    pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50, 100]
                    disableRowSelectionOnClick
                    onPaginationModelChange={handlePaginationModelChange}
                    checkboxSelection
                    onSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionModel) => {
                        setSelectionModel(newSelectionModel);
                    }}
                    paginationMode="server"
                    pagination
                    pageSize={5}
                    slots={{
                        pagination: CustomPagination,
                        columnUnsortedIcon: CustomUnsortedIcon,
                    }}
                    localeText={{ noRowsLabel: 'No Data Found' }}
                />
```

I want to persist my selectionModel state to persist when I change page and call api to update my row and toatalCount State